# Batch file how to insert the text in next column?

Tags: batch-file

I have an issue on inserting data into an excel sheet.

**Example:** I have *bat* file like below;

> echo %computername%; %userdomain% ; %username%; %date% ; %time%  >>
>   C:\Server\user\palani\logout.csv

**This bat file returns the output like this:**

> ABCD-D-1256G; DIR ; viswa; Wed 09/02/2015 ; 19:17:11.85

The output below is stored in excel sheet single column.

**But I want to output a separate column like this:**

> |ABCD-D-1256G |DIR | viswa |Wed 09/02/2015 | 19:17:11.85

Could you please guide me how to use the tab function or delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

To add a new line you should add a:

```
& echo.
```

instead of the >>.

If I understand you're question right.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is good, the only problem is the delimiter you use. check what is your List separator in your computer regional settings (control panel -> region and Language -> additionnal settings -> List separator).

Make sure your echo ouput the same thing to separate column than your computer regional settings. If your List separator is set to colon then you need to change your code to look like this:

```
echo %computername%,%userdomain%,%username%,%date%,%time% >> C:\Server\user\palani\logout.csv
```

Comment: Thanks lot Cividan, above your idea is working for me this is my actual requirement i like this stackoverflow